# vb.net storing large amounts of data

Tags: vb.net

I need to store a large list of id's and load them into my .NET project the id's are like  -

```
 1:1:1:1
 9:2:5:3
 0:2:6:4
```

the list is roughly 15k lines.

ive tried storing the list online and reading it line by line but it takes 3-4 minutes just to get all the information, also tried downloading the text file and then reading it line by line but that's also incredibly slow.

can anyone suggest a better way ?

edit - code for reading from text file

```
 Private Sub frmIkovItemID_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        Dim fStream As New System.IO.FileStream("c:\proxy.txt", IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fStream)

        Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
            itemIDs.Add(sReader.ReadLine)
        Loop
    Catch o As Exception
        MsgBox(o.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: 3-4 minutes to read 15k lines? That should be quick - I suspect your file IO code has a problem. Could you post that code?

Comment: first rule of SO: post your code ;)

Comment: sorry i forgot to post the code as well, added it now

Comment: Highly unlikely that the posted code would take more than a few (fractions) of a second to run. What is itemIDs?

Comment: its a list of numbers in the format 00:00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to store a large list of [...]

What you really mean is that you want to persist data.

Reading and writing in a file is a kind of persistence, yes, but a better solution would be to use a database. Especially if you are using a large amount of data. ([Why use a database instead of just saving your data to disk?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190482/why-use-a-database-instead-of-just-saving-your-data-to-disk))

If you don't know how to use a database in vb.net, have a look at the [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821765).